# Limit of a inductive sequence

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

Suppose we have a sequence $(a_n)$ with

$a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{3}(2a_n+\frac{7}{a_n^2})$

I have to show that the limit of this sequence is $\sqrt[3]{7}$.

I can show that $a_{n+1}<a_n$ and that $\sqrt[3]{7}<a_n$. But how can I conclude from this that the limit ist $\sqrt[3]{7}$.

I mean it is obvious but how to prove it in a formal way?

Comment: Note that this is Newton's method for $f(x)=x^3-7$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have proved that the sequence is monotonic and bounded. The limit must exist, say that it is $L$. Now you can take limits on both sides of the recurrence equality:

$$\lim a_{n+1}=\lim\frac13\left(2a_n+\frac 7{a_n^2}\right)$$
Therefore
$$L=\frac13\left(2L+\frac7{L^2}\right)$$
The final step is solving this for $L$.